# Pass username password in http as in curl

Tags: java, scala

I´m using a curl query

```
curl http://username:password@ip:8091/pools/default/buckets/price/docs/06d4c5d8-71d3-4216-89ac-9da44f9b5c54
```

Ans works fine and the document is returned.

But now I need to use http get form my scala code

```
val req = Http(createURI(uri, path))
      .headers(headers)
      .method(method)
      .body(body)
      .timeout(connTimeoutMs = CONNECT_TIMEOUT, readTimeoutMs = READ_TIMEOUT)
      .option(HttpOptions.allowUnsafeSSL)
```

the uri right now is the same

```
uri = URI.create("http://username:password@ip:8091/pools/default/buckets/price/docs/06d4c5d8-71d3-4216-89ac-9da44f9b5c54")
```

But when I run it I receive 401 Unauthorized.

any idea how to pass the username and password?

Comment: You could add an `Authorization` header. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: You can base64-encode user and password and then send it as an `Authorization` header with your request

Answer (score 0):

You can user -u parameter of curl

```
curl -u <userid>:<userpassword> http://ip:8091/pools/default/buckets/price/docs/06d4c5d8-71d3-4216-89ac-9da44f9b5c54
```

Ref: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html